# MagicPython(.gyp) to Python(.py) in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have have installed VS Code and Python 3 using brew on my mac.

Added the Python extension from Microsoft.
Works fine.

My problem is that I don't see PYTHON as a possible format in the drop down list when I am trying to do a "Save as". Only MagicPython is shown as an option.

I can force with an extension say `test.py` or I select the MagicPython option, but it gets saved as `test.gyp`

No Difference in functionality, but would like my files to get saved as `.py`
Is this possible?

Comment: So you have a file named `something.gyp` and you are trying to rename it to `something.py`? Or you have a new text buffer that you never saved and you want to name it `something.py`? And what OS are you on?

Comment: @BrettCannon I rename without any problem. My problem is why is Python not an option for me in the dropdown when I am doing a "save as" < filename>

Comment: Do you **only** have the Python extension installed, or do you have other Python-related extensions like MagicPython installed? If you have others, I would try disabling them to see if that changes things (i.e. if you have the MagicPython extension installed that could be "winning" for the `.py` file extension)

Comment: Seems to be a bug that's related to how Electron gets the file type. Not sure. Definitely fixable as a vscode thing though. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98504

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problems on my Mac too.

Save it as `test.gyp` first.

Then open it again in **VS Code** and go to `File -> Save As`.

Now it should be having a name of `test.gyp`, change this to `test.py` and click `Save`.

It should now be in the `.py` format, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This question could probably be closed as the mentioned issues are clearly solved in vs code Version: 1.55.0. Currently magicpython besides being default is associated to many different python file extensions - as you can see in the picture I am attaching here.[image: MagicPython_Associated_Files]